# ERROR TypeError angular undefined in a service

Tags: angular, soap

I created a service for a SOAP call.

```
public getCommonIndexes(categories: string[]): string {
  console.log('Response form in service layer: ', categories);

  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open('POST', this.appConfig.getConfig().apiUrl + '' + this.appConfig.getConfig().getCommonIndexes, true);

  // build SOAP request
  const soapRequest =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
    'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' +
    'xmlns:bran="http://www.bottomline.com/soap/branch/">' +
    '<soapenv:Header/>' +
    '<soapenv:Body>' +
    '<bran:CallBranch soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">' +
    '<JSONRequest xsi:type="xsd:string">' + JSON.stringify(categories) + '</JSONRequest>' +
    '</bran:CallBranch>\n' +
    '</soapenv:Body>\n' +
    '</soapenv:Envelope>';

  console.log('SOAP REQUEST ');
  console.log(soapRequest.toString());

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        this.returnValue = xmlhttp.responseText;
        return this.returnValue;
      }
    }
  };
  // // Send the POST request
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  xmlhttp.send(soapRequest);
  return this.returnValue;
}
```

Here are my variables:

```
replacement = [
'<html>', '<body>', '<h1>', 'Response', '</h1>', '<p>', 'The', 'server', 'returned', 'these', 'fields:', '<table', 'border="1">',
'<tr>', '<td>', 'JSONResponse', '</td>', '</tr>', '</table>', '</body>', '</html>', '<p>', '<td>', '</td>'
];
xmlReplacement = [
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>',
'<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">',
'<SOAP-ENV:Body>', '<CallBranchOut xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance">',
'<JSONResponse xsi:type="xsd:string">', '</JSONResponse>', '</CallBranchOut>', '</SOAP-ENV:Body>', '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'];

categoriesResponseModel: CategoriesResponseModel;
// category: CategoryModel;
categories: CategoryModel[] = [];
selectedCategories: CategoryModel[] = [];
indexes: IndexModel[] = [];
@Output() indexesSelected  = new EventEmitter<IndexModel[]>();
categoriesDescriptionName: string[] = [];
categoriesList: string[] = [];
```

In the component, I inject the ApiService in the constructor :

```
constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
  console.log('# constructor() called');
  this.getCategories();
}


getSelectedIndexesList(): void {
  console.log('original: ', this.indexes);
  console.log('# buildIndexList() called');
  this.categoriesList = [];
  for (const category of this.selectedCategories) {
    // categoryNames
    this.categoriesList.push(category.DocDescription);
    // this.categoryNames.push(category.CategoryName);
    this.categoriesDescriptionName = this.categoriesList.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.categoriesDescriptionName));
  }

  let response = '';
  if (!!this.categoriesDescriptionName) {
    response = this.apiService
      .getCommonIndexes(this.categoriesDescriptionName)
      .replace(/\n/g, '')
      .replace(/(&quot;)/g, '"');
    this.xmlReplacement.forEach(
      item => {
        response = response.replace(item, '');
      }
    );
  }
  console.log('response ', response);
  this.categoriesList = [];
  this.categoriesList = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log('categories ', this.categoriesList);
  // for (const selectedCategory of  this.categoriesList) {
  //   for (const selectedIndex of selectedCategory.Indexes) {
  //     this.indexes.push(selectedIndex);
  //     console.log('**************************************');
  //     console.log(this.indexes);
  //     console.log('**************************************');
  //   }
  // }
}
```

In the template, I want to retrieve the result of my call on click event. I'm using prime ng multiselect for this :

```
<p-multiSelect
  [options]="categories"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
  defaultLabel="Select a Category"
  optionLabel="CategoryName"
  class="multiselect-custom"
  (onChange)="getSelectedCategoriesList()"
>
  <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItems" >
    <div class="itemlist itemlist-value" *ngFor="let option of selectedCategories">
      <div>{{option.DocDescription }}</div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!selectedCategories || selectedCategories.length === 0" class="country-placeholder">
      Select categories
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-category pTemplate="item">
    <div class="itemlist">
      <div>{{category.value.DocDescription }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>

<button (click)="getIndexes($event)" class="btn btn-primary" >OK</button>

<p *ngIf="selectedCategories.length > 0">
  <span *ngFor="let cat of categoriesDescriptionName">
    {{ cat }}
  </span>
</p>
```

I obtain this error message:
ERROR TypeError: this.apiService.getCommonIndexes(...) is undefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: While there may be other issues with the code that are causing the immediate error, eventually, you will run into the problem outlined in the above question, since `returnValue` in `getCommonIndexes` is likely not populated by the time you return it. For the immediate error, you'll need to show the entire `ApiService` declaration.